# QTime change AM to PM and vice versa

Tags: qt, qtime, qtimeedit

I want to change the "AM" to "PM" string and vice versa in Qt.

I created a `QTimeEdit` in .ui and I set the `displayFormat` to `"HH::mm a"` but I always get AM even we're in afternoon now. How do I change the code to get a display either "AM" or "PM"?

I know that there's function members named `amText()` and `pmText()`, but they return a string.

Answer (score 0):

The correct format string to get AM or PM depending on the actual time is [`"ap"`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toString). Thus, change your format string to `"HH:mm ap"`.

Answer (score -1):

you should use "h:m:s ap"